# Integrating x and y components of speed separately to get distance traveled?

Tags: calculus, integration, parametric

Let's say I have a particle moving in the xy-plane, with its position at any $t$ being $(x(t),y(t))$. In order to calculate distance traveled, I have been taught to integrate $\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2} dt$. However, I'm wondering why I can't just integrate $|x'(t)|dt$ to get the distance traveled in the x-direction, and integrate $|y'(t)|dt$ to get the distance in the y-direction, and then add the two? In order to find displacement, we can drop the absolute value and it seems to work just fine.

Comment: This would only work for a square grid like New York streets. Its shorter to take a diagonal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Travelling from $(0,0)$ at a velocity of $\mathbf i+\mathbf j,$ the distance travelled over $[t=0\;,\;t=1]$ is $\sqrt2,$ but your method gives $2$ instead.

Essentially, you are asking whether $$\int_a^b\sqrt{(x'(t))^2}+\sqrt{(y'(t))^2} \,\mathrm dt$$equals $$\int_a^b\sqrt{(x'(t))^2+(y'(t))^2} \,\mathrm dt.$$ For $a<b,$ $$\int_a^b\left|x'(t)\right|+|y'(t)| \,\mathrm dt\ge\int_a^b\left|\begin{pmatrix} x'(t) \cr y'(t) \end{pmatrix}  \right| \,\mathrm dt.$$

Answer (score 2):

If you move in a circle, with
$$
\left\{
\begin{align}
x(t)&=R\cos t,\\
y(t)&=R\sin t,
\end{align}
\right.
\qquad t\in[0,2\pi],
$$
you get 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{x'^2+y'^2}dt=2\pi R
$$
while
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}|x'|dt=\int_0^\pi R\sin tdt+\int_\pi^{2\pi}(-R\sin t)dt=2R+2R=4R
$$
so you get the distance traveled along $x$, a diameter in the go and another diameter in return.